# Which is a better way to use a react hook to check if a value is present in array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I want to extract permission checking logic into a React hook like this:

```js
function usePermission(permission) {
  const permissions = useSelector(state => state.auth.permissions);

  return useMemo(() => permissions.includes(permission), [permissions, permission]);
}

// elsewhere

function SomeComponent() {
  const canDoSomething = usePermission('can_do_something');

  return <button disabled={!canDoSomething}>Do something</button>; 
}
```

My colleague suggests another approach:

```js
function useCheckPermission() {
  const permissions = useSelector(state => state.auth.permissions);

  return useCallback((permission) => permissions.includes(permission), [permissions]);
}

// elsewhere

function SomeComponent() {
  const checkPermission = useCheckPermission();

  return <button disabled={!checkPermission('can_do_something')}>Do something</button>; 
}
```

My question is: which is a better/more idiomatic way of doing this in React?

Also, is there a point in using `useMemo` in the first case and/or `useCallback` in the second?

Comment: I've written almost this exact custom hook before. I took the 1st approach minus the `useMemo`. The `useMemo` is probably fine to use here, but I never ran into performance issues without it and it was used all over the place

Comment: I guess the main difference here is that if you need to check multiple permissions in the same component, you would need to use X amount of `usePermission()` hooks (I frequently had 3+ in a single component), where as `useCheckPermission()` could be used once and the function could be called X amount of times. It seems like an issue of preference

Comment: Straight from the React docs: "`useCallback(fn, deps)` is equivalent to `useMemo(() => fn, deps)`". In other words, `useCallback` and `useMemo` are effectively two sides of the same memoization coin. This is a subjective question and the answer sort of depends on personal preference. Not everything needs to be a React hook.

Comment: @DrewReese, yes, I know that, the last part of my question was just about whether or not there is a point in using memoization here at all.

Comment: That's still a bit subjective. Is there a point? Sure, to provide a stable reference. If that matters depends on the greater context where that value is referenced. If all it does is trigger a few extra rerenders here or there, and that doesn't matter performance-wise, then you could likely forego memoization. If performance *is* an issue, and I mean actual audited and measured performance degradation, then by all means, start looking to optimize your app where you can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see it depends.

first approach looks more suitable when your memo values shared in different jsx tags in your components,

later one could be used to pass different arguments in different jsx tags.

Frankly speaking, I won't use useMemo/useCallback in neither way. you already use useSelector for performance. Seems over performance work done in single custom hook

Comment: Thank you! After having my brain on and off of this, I decided that with the second approach we won't have to `useSelector` the permission set multiple times for multiple permissions.

As for memoization, it's kinda become a habit to memoize return values of hooks to avoid unexpected updates.